# Blobs in SVG only using filters

Tags: vector, svg, filter

I want to generate "pseudo-random" organic looking blobs in SVG (without JavaScript).
I was wondering if this could be done solely in SVG, using filters (like feTurbulence and feDisplacementMap), but still have a smooth finish. The "seed" could then determine the shape of the blob. I could both determine the shape, keep it "determistic" (the seed would be fixed) and get different blobs.

I was able to get circles to not be so "round" with the said filters, but it is anything but smooth or blob-looking.

```
<svg width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 220 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="displacementFilter">
      <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.05" numOctaves="2" result="turbulence" seed="2"/>
      <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic" scale="5" xChannelSelector="R" yChannelSelector="G"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" style="filter: url(#displacementFilter)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you please include an example of the before and after of what you're hoping to create using SVG filters? "blob" is pretty non-descript as the size and general shape of the blobs has great effect.

Comment: Perhaps the third demo in [this post](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/03/12/image-distortion-effects-with-svg-filters/) is along the lines of what you want?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What kind of blob are you actually trying to achieve?  I mean how blobby do you want it to be. Your example is more like a roughened circle TBH.

Comment: Also, I can think of better ways to generate random blobs than using filters. What software do you have access to?  In Inkscape for example, it's [pretty easy to draw](https://imgur.com/a/rOYLeSK) randomized dodecahedrons with rounded corners.

Comment: What I mean by blob is along the lines of https://www.blobmaker.app/

Comment: As for software, I use too often Notepad to create SVG.

Comment: You'd be better off with a GLSL shader to create that sort of warping. Or animating the points of an SVG path. Filters are not the way to create that sort of thing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GLSL shaders. Could you give me a link to an example where this would apply please?

Comment: Google 2D metaball shadertoy

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use filters to do this.

Try Inkscape's Stars and Polygons tool. As a starting point, set the tool controls to Regular Polygons, corners 3, randomized 0.370, and rounded corners 0.150. Feel free to adjust these settings as required.

Example

[image]